# How to send mail when the date/time reached?

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I have a django website which is integrated to sqlite database.

It has a database table field with date/time stamp and email field. How to trigger a mail to user in email field with when the date/time field is equal to the current date/time.

Comment: Have you tried to schedule jobs or email sending task using celery?

Answer (score 0):

I think Celery would be a good fit. It is used for periodic tasks in Django.

You can have a periodic task which repeats every minute *(or any other time-scale)* that compares the current time against all of your database entries' `datetime` field to determine whether or not to send an email.

Link: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html